# HTTPX DeprecationWarning: Use 'content=<...>' to upload raw bytes/text content

Tags: python, pip, httpx

I installed a project that has httpx in the code and it seems that there is a method deprecated in its code. I looked for a solution but I don't find any solution for it. ( Also, I have run it before and it was working "2 weeks ago").

The error appears as follows:

```bash
Deprecation error in lib/python3.8/site-packages/httpx/_content.py:201:
DeprecationWarning: Use 'content=<...>' to upload raw bytes/text content.
warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning)
```

httpx version is `httpx==0.23.1`

Does anyone know how to silence or fix this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I installed a project that has httpx

That's a bug in the project and the only way to avoid the `DeprecationWarning` is to fix the project. See https://www.python-httpx.org/compatibility/#request-content :

> For uploading raw text or binary content we prefer to use a `content` parameter…

> Using the `data=<text/byte content>` will raise a deprecation warning, and is expected to be fully removed with the HTTPX 1.0 release.